# Native Ordering of a Model's Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know how Rails orders a model's attributes natively?

My issue is this:

I have a model I have been using for a long time called `Device`.
In `devices/show.html.erb` I show its attributes using something akin to:

```
<% @device.attributes.each do |k,v| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= k %></td>
    <td><%= v %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have decided to add an attribute that is related to the 5th attribute in the model's attributes, but when I run the create_column migration for it, it appears at the end of this list (as it is the last attribute to be added).

I suspect Rails orders its attributes by column-creation time, as I have attempted to move the column to the correct place in my database, and declare the attribute sooner in my attr_accessible list, to no avail. Moving the column in `schema.rb` and rebuilding the database would probably work, but this is something I can't do. I could hack it into the right spot in the view, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution first.

Is there any way I can do this without enforcing ordering across the whole attribute list?

Comment: This is just asking for trouble; order them yourself before presenting them to the view, otherwise you're at the mercy of however a specific version decides to order them.

Comment: Ouch, having something dependent on the nth position of a column sounds like a really bad idea. As you've observed, you cannot guarantee the order / position (not without a whole lot of monkeying around, and even then I wouldn't rely on that). I think you are better off describing the specific scenario you're trying to accomplish with this ordering; we can probably help you find a much safer solution.

Comment: I had not intended to be reliant on any ordering of the attributes of this model (other than view-consistency I guess), so I was not particularly concerned with being at the mercy of the attribute-ordering decisions taken by specific versions. Obviously this has (very slightly) changed so I will introduce ordering to the view for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this:

1- Get the column_names (if you don't want to do it manually)

```
column_names = Device.column_names.inject([]) { |arr,e| arr.push(e) }
```

2- Modify the order that you want (i.e, a column name that you care about)

3- Evaluate each on `@device`

```
column_names.each_with_object({}) { |m, hash| hash[m] = @device.send(m) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails migrations lets you specify where to add a column with the `:after` option:

```
add_column :your_table, :column_name, :data_type, after: :related_column
```

This could help. But, as this is a presentation concern, I'd order the attributes in a helper.

Comment: AFAIK the `:after` option is database dependent and is a MySQLism.